# Excel SIN not working with this simple syntax

Tags: excel, trigonometry, calculator

Simple question here for Excel addict:

```
 =0.23-0.0373*SIN(B2-PI)



X      Y    
0      0.24         #NAME?
0.1   -0.758334166  #NAME?
0.2   -1.746693308  #NAME?
0.3   -2.715202067  #NAME?
```

does not work (column on the right) , why can this be?

Don t see why should not work like that, however info on mouse show this syntax.

Also checked syntax, and ... no clue.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error is that [PI](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/pi-HP005209214.aspx) is a function in excel. It should be like this:

```
=0.23-0.0373*SIN(B2-PI())
```